# Web application development to desktop application development in java

Tags: java, swing

I am planning to develop an cross platform application in `Java`. I am working for web application like GWT, ZKOSS, Vaadin. I know that `Swing` is great but i am not sure how to use styles or customize it. Do we have any other framework so that we can use css to customize?

NOTE :
My development environment is ubuntu 64 bit system, so i can't use `JavaFX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create applications with native controls using [SWT-library](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) if you don't like Swing. It is used by the Eclipse development environment. You could also try using [Apache Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/), which has it's own markup language for defining UI's.

You might also consider using full blown frameworks like [Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform) or [Netbeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html). I don't think any of these allow to use CSS though

Answer (score 1):

Java FX 2 is excellent for this.

Comment: But it is not available for linux 64 bit. I am sorry i forgot to mention it.My development environment is ubuntu 64 bit system.

Comment: Not as a production ready release, but as a developer preview it is. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Comment: @Ramesh add that info to the question

Comment: So the developer preview might be good enough for you to develop with.